# Finding throuput of CPU and Hardrive on Solaris

Tags: solaris, hard-drive, iostat

How do I find the throughput of a CPU and the hard disk on an OpenSolaris machine?
Using `mpstat` or `iostat`?

I'm having a hard time identifying the throughput if it is given at all in the commands output.
For example, in [`mpstat`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18752_01/html/816-5166/mpstat-1m.html) there is very little explanation as to what the columns mean.

I've been using the syscl column divided by time interval to find the throughput but to be honest I have no idea what a system call truly is.

I'm trying to to analyze a hardrive and CPU while writing a file to the hardisk and when at rest.

Comment: I think you need to better specify what you mean by CPU throughput.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To measure disk throughput with iostat, use a command like 'iostat -dxnz 2'

Every 2 seconds (the 2 in the command) this will give you the number of writes and reads/second and the number of kilobytes written and read for every active disk and tape device in a system. Using the %b (percentage of time the device is busy) figure it is possible to make some extrapolations as to the spare I/O capacity a device has, but remember that changing the character of I/O (e.g. moving from pure read to a mixture of reads & writes) will change the apparent I/O performance of a device dramatically.

Answer (score 0):

Since OpenSolaris (and newer) uses ZFS use `zpool iostat -v 2` (rather than just `iostat`). You'll get the I/O for the pool all the way down to the individual vdevs.